# How to get InstallR to download latest version of R?

Tags: rlink, paclets

I just ran `InstallR` and it installed an incredibly old version of R from year 2011.

```
Needs["RLink`"];
InstallR[];
REvaluate["R.version.string"]
```

> ```
> {"R version 2.14.0 (2011-10-31)"}
> ```

Is there anyway to make `InstallR` download a more recent version?  I know I can install R outside of Mathematica and use the `"RHomeLocation"` option but I am hoping this is not necessary.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no way to do this at the moment. We plan to update bundled R to a recent version soon, but that won't happen before 11.3. In the mean time, you will need to install a version of R externally and use "RHomeLocation".

Comment: Perhaps, as a hack, you can format the paclet yourself. It seems that `InstallR` uses `PacletFind@"RLinkRuntime"`. If you look in the paclet for this you see SystemFiles > (system) > R. Presumably by swapping that out that R with a newer copy of R you can get it in. That shouldn't tough to do. (note that mostly this just frees you from using `"RHomeLocation"`)

Comment: @b3m2a1 That's a wrong advice in this case. The bundled R version has been built in a special way, having been patched on the object code level so that libraries can find each other via hard-wired relative paths without any environmental variables being set. Replacing that version with an external one would just break this mechanism, so this won't work.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin that's good to know, thanks.

Comment: @b3m2a1 Sure, was glad to help.